# Units of parameters in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dimensional-analysis

Suppose I have the system $$I'(t) = \frac{\alpha\beta I}{r+\alpha I} (1-I) - \mu I$$ where $I$ is a unitless quantity giving the portion of a population (in this case, total infected/total population, so $I \le 1$). Suppose the units of $\alpha$ is $h/m$, where $h$ and $m$ are two arbitrary quantities. The same is true for $\beta$. That is, $\beta$ has units $h/m$. $\mu$ is a probability, so the final expression is unitless. However, $I'(t)$ is obviously the derivative of $I$ with respect to time, so its units should be $1/t$, as $I$ is unitless. How is this possible? How do I find the units of $r$ (the force of mortality)?

Comment: If alpha and beta have the same units, while I is unitless, then the first term has the same units as alpha. You have units squared in the numerator

Comment: Some context: $\alpha$ is transmission rate from (infected) humans to mosquitoes, $\beta$ is transmission rate from (infected) mosquitoes to humans, $r$ is natural death rate of mosquitoes.

Comment: What they are measured in? I would guess $[t]^{-1}$, where $t$ is time? Then I don't see a problem

Comment: For example, $\alpha$ is the product of human bites per mosquito multiplied by a probability factor. Does $\alpha$ still have units of $t^{-1}$?

Comment: Then it's not clear to me. Maybe not. You should know the units really, as you are familiar with the problem. From what you state, time is not involved. And bites or mosquitoes are not units. So alpha and beta should be dimensionless

Comment: Assuming they're rates, I assume the dimensions are indeed as you suggested. Thank you for the help